# Kafka - Message with different key stored in same partition

Tags: apache-kafka, partitioning, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to store Messages with different key to different partition.

**For example:**

```
ProducerRecord<String, String> rec1 = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("topic", "key1", line);
ProducerRecord<String, String> rec2 = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("topic", "key2", line);
producer.send(rec1);
producer.send(rec2);
```

But when i try to run my Producer class, it always stored in single partition.

As per documentation, `DefaultPartitioner` uses `message key hash code` to find the partition.
I also saw this question [Kafka partition key not working properly‏](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373594/kafka-partition-key-not-working-properly), but i cannot find `ByteArrayPartitioner` class in 0.9.x version of Kafka Client library.

```
props.put("partitioner.class", "kafka.producer.ByteArrayPartitioner")
```

**Update:** I am creating the topic on the fly using code.

If i create a topic with partitions manually, then its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If topics are created "on the fly", the are created with number of partitions according to `num.partitions` parameters (with default value `1`). And if you have only one partitions, all data will go to this single partitions.

However, keep in mind, even if you have multiple partitions, a partitions can still get different keys assigned! Even if you have num-partitions == num-distinct-keys there might be hash collisions, assigning two different keys to the same partitions (and leaving some partitions empty).

If you want to **ensure** that different keys always go to different partitions, you need to use a consumer partitioner or specify the partition number directly.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.